# Vue.js, how to pass boolean on input value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to pass boolean value on input, like

```
  v-bind:value="false"
```

but it doesn't work, on `true` it work but it doesn't work on `false`, what could be the cause ?

Comment: What is not working ? It should work. Check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0w7q9d6o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you can either use `""` (empty string) instead of `false`, or reorganize your component that uses this property. Quoting the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#boolean-attributes):

> Boolean attributes are attributes that can indicate `true` / `false`
> values by its presence on an element. For example, `disabled` is one of
> the most commonly used boolean attributes.
>
> v-bind works a bit differently in this case:
>
> `<button :disabled="isButtonDisabled">Button</button>`
>
> The disabled attribute will be included if isButtonDisabled has a truthy value. It will also be included if the value is an empty string, maintaining
> consistency with `<button disabled="">`.
>
> **For other falsy values the attribute will be omitted.**